# Impact of maven.artifact.threads

Tags: maven, build

From [what I see](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/configuration.html), the default number of threads when downloading artifacts in maven is `5`.
I have tried to increase it in my project to `10` and I do not see much difference.
(It takes ~30 minutes of downloading for a clean build, CPU has 16 cores) 
Is there any documentation which shows the impact of increasing that value on total artifacts downloading time?
Is there a way to make maven display in logs which thread is downloading which artifact?

Comment: The number of CPU's is not that much important...the download speed is more important... and really downloading takes ~30 minutes ??? BTW: Which Maven version do you use? –

Comment: @khmarbaise Maven `3.5.4`. It takes 30 minutes thanks to JFrog. I am doing dockerized builds. Managed to fix `go-offline`, but each `pom.xml` change makes it build from scratch.

Comment: First use most recent version of Maven ... 3.8.6 second why does it take so long...is the download taking so much time? Also I recommend to measure the real thing: https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-buildtime-profiler Can you tell how many tests running / how many classes you have etc. Also do you use the most recent versions of plugins etc.

Comment: Yes, more than 95% of time is downloading artifacts.I have disabled tests `-DskipTests` Building code, running plugins checks etc is not a problem. The only problem is very long downloading of artifacts.

Comment: So this means increasing threads will not help...the bottleneck sounds like the download itself (speed of the repo manager?)? or Network..